# Is it better to use MS Word or MS Excel for planning months and weeks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, planning

I want to make weekly planning for the main tasks for the months ahead. So, I can look every week at this plan and put the tasks in my To Do list app or Calendar.

Is it best to use MS Word or MS Excel for such tables?. 4 Weeks for each month, and to make space for each week to write the main tasks (Something similar to Gantt charts).

Comment: Why not use a calendar app instead? In fact any proper tasks app would have a calendar view builtin. Excel is for tabular data, and Word is for text processing

Comment: As above, none. Also, to use this service properly, ask a question for recommending a software for your purpose, rather than auto-answering it partially yourself.